# How can I invoke `exec` to chainload one WASM program from another?

Tags: c, exec, webassembly, emsdk

How can I invoke `exec` in WASM? When I try the example below, it gives [error `45`](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/f9f613324551b001564aa226b9ede221b7e0b3ce/sys/sys/errno.h#L98) (`Operation not supported`). Is there some flag to enable `exec`? Is `callee.wasm` not the right file to `exec`?

**Terminal:**

```text
> emcc callee.c -o callee.wasm
> emcc caller.c --embed-file callee.wasm -o index.html
> # will be used through index.html, but node is faster for development
> # note: MEMFS working directory is "/" and "/callee.wasm" exists
> # https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/Filesystem-API.html
> node index.js
Caller
Caller: 45
```

**`caller.c`**

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  printf("Caller\n");

  char *args[] = {"./callee.wasm", NULL};
  execvp(args[0], args);

  printf("Caller: %d\n", errno);
}
```

**`callee.c`**

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Success!\n");
}
```

---

It should be made clear that this is simplified version, so do not suggest putting `printf("Success!\n");` in `caller.c` and avoiding `exec` entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you can’t, short of reimplementing `exec` yourself.

Point of order first: `errno` 45 is *not* `EOPNOTSUPP` under Emscripten as the question would suggest; it is, in fact, `ENOEXEC` (see [`arch/emscripten/bits/errno.h`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/6f3cfe3b534af4551f9d3ccf296f92c76589c465/system/lib/libc/musl/arch/emscripten/bits/errno.h#L10) and [`wasi/api.h`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/6f3cfe3b534af4551f9d3ccf296f92c76589c465/system/include/wasi/api.h#L341)).  `errno` numbers are generally not consistent between platforms, and there is no reason why `errno` numbers in a BSD libc would agree with Emscripten libc.

And the Emscripten libc [hardcodes `execve` to always fail with `ENOEXEC`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/6f3cfe3b534af4551f9d3ccf296f92c76589c465/system/lib/libc/emscripten_libc_stubs.c#L159-L167), and the entire `exec*` family of libc calls ultimately ends up there, [including `execvp`](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/6f3cfe3b534af4551f9d3ccf296f92c76589c465/system/lib/libc/musl/src/process/execvp.c#L39).  The symbol is declared as weak, however, so you can in principle replace the default implementation with your own.  How you are going to accomplish that, I leave up to you.